# What algorithm should be used to extract patterns from datasets?

Tags: machine-learning

I have some datasets related to climate change and epidemic spread rate.

I would like to know which machine learning algorithm should I apply to extract the patterns from the datasets, thanks.

Comment: @Alan Yes I did, I couldn't find the answer on search engines, which is why I posted my questions here. Your comment is as good as no comment

Comment: while you may have trouble on general search engines, academic search engines [will give you something](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=modeling+epidemic+spread&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u need to do regression analysis to identify the effect of climate on epidemic spread rate.